# Scale the rectangle detected in OpenCV Face Recognition

Tags: python, opencv

Using OpenCV (in Python), I have drawn a rectangle around the detected face. This is done simply by:

```
cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x+width, y+height), (255,255,255), 4, lineType=-1)
```

[image]

I want to scale this rectangle say around 3 times such that it is still centred around the same point. It should look like the rectangle in yellow border:

[image]

How should this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate center point of your first rectangle, than create a rectangle with 3x width and height:

```
center_x = (x + x + width) // 2
center_y = (y + y + height) // 2
cv2.rectangle(img, (center_x-3*width, center_y-3*height), (center_x+3*width, center_y+3*height), (255,255,255), 4, lineType=-1)
```